# × TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to upload audio file in React application but am running into a problem. When I try to upload a file, it works just fine But when i click on play button i am running into a problem.

This is my code

```
const addAudioFile = (e) => {
if (e.target.files) {
  setAudio(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files));
  var aud = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files));
  setCurrentAudio(aud);
}
```

};

HTML part

```
              <div>

              <VtButton
              onClick={() => setIsActiveAlert(!isActiveAlert)}
              name="Select Alert Tone"
              className="selectTone"
               />

                {notify.map((item) => (
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <span>
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          id="wav"
                          name="audio"
                          onClick={() => setAudio(item.url)}
                        />
                        <span for="wav">
                          {item.name}
                        </span>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}

                <div>
                  <input
                    id="chooseFile"
                    className="form-control  select-fileType"
                    type="file"
                    placeholder={t("COMMON.CHOOSE_FILE")}
                    style={{ width: "85%" }}
                    accept=".wav"
                    autoPlay={false}
                    audiolist={audiolist}
                    beforeAudioUpload={beforeAudioUpload}
                    autocomplete="off"
                    onChange={addAudioFile}
                  />
                  <VtButton
                    className="audioSelectBtn"
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    name={buttonName}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create from `event.target.files[0]` like this.

```
if (e.target.files) {
  setAudio(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.target.files[0]));
  var aud = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.target.files[0]));
  setCurrentAudio(aud);
}
```